# Building a date string in c

Tags: c

I am currently working on a c project and I am trying to get the date from the system and build that into a string.

I am very new to c so I'm currently learning as I go along but I cannot get this to work. Below is the code that I have

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
char currentDate[13];
char day[3];
char month[3];
char year[5];
char hour[3];
char min[3];
sprintf(day, "%02d", t->tm_mday, sizeof(day));
sprintf(month, "%02d", t->tm_mon+1, sizeof(month));
sprintf(year, "%04d", t->tm_year + 1900, sizeof(year));
sprintf(hour, "%02d", t->tm_hour, sizeof(hour));
sprintf(min, "%02d", t->tm_min, sizeof(min));
strcat(currentDate, day);
strcat(currentDate, month);
strcat(currentDate, year);
strcat(currentDate, hour);
strcat(currentDate, min);
printf("Current Date: %s", currentDate);
```

When it does the printf it just prints a load of rubbish e.g.

> Current Date: ÃÃxÂ·ZÂ¤Ã¿Â·Ã¸ÃÃÂ©Ã´ÃÃ¿Â·^XÃÃÂ©<95>ÃºÃ¾Â·^F^FÃ^P^_

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: have you got a null terminator at the end of each string?

Comment: By the way, you might want to look into the [`ctime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/ctime) function

Comment: and it looks that you have two variable `currentDate`, which is not allowed

Comment: that duplicate `curentDate` was there by mistake. Have now fixed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would consider using [ctime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime) and/or [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime). It might get you what you want without messing too much with strings and time fields.

With strftime:

```
char text[100];
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm *t = localtime(&now);


strftime(text, sizeof(text)-1, "%d %m %Y %H:%M", t);
printf("Current Date: %s", text);
```

Comment: It is not necessary to subtract 1 of the size of the array. The terminating NULL-byte is counted. Also, it is advisable to check the return value for errors -- they are however indistinguishable from an empty string.

Answer (score 7):

Change the first strcat to the following.  `currentDate` otherwise is not initialized.

```
strcpy(currentDate, day);
```

However, it might be simpler to use [`strftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime).

Answer (score 2):

```
char currentDate[12] = {'\0'};
```

currentDate contains random data and is not initialized hence strcat looks for the zero terminating the string.

Answer (score 1):

@markWilkins answer is correct however it might be easier to printf the string all at once.

```
sprintf(currentDate, "%02d%02d%04d%02d%02d", t->tm_mday, t->tm_mon+1, 
 t->tm_year + 1900, t->tm_hour,t->tm_min);
```

This allows you to see the format as one and means you don't have to do all the string manipulation.

Also note that sprintf does not take the maximun size as a parameter